# One of my two cores suddenly flatlines at zero percent

Tags: cpu, cpu-load, multi-core

I've been using Ubuntu for about three months, and twice now the first core of my dual-core laptop suddenly flatlined at zero percent for no apparent reason, while the second one seemed unaffected. Does anyone know why this may be happening? Should I be worried?

Edit:  Here are some screenshots. The first one was taken soon after it happened.

[image: IMG]

[image: IMG]

Comment: Add also the output of `dmesg | tail -n 50` when this happens.

Comment: Also try opening a terminal and running `stress --cpu 2 --io 4 --vm 2 --vm-bytes 128M --timeout 10s` and then watch the system monitor while that runs. You might have to `sudo apt-get install stress` to install it. `stress` is a tool to impose load on a CPU for testing. It's just an easy way to check whether your CPU will actually work when told to do so.